# How do I compile MODFLOW6 on Mac?

Tags: macos, meson-build

I'm familiar with cmake, however I don't see a cmake file in the MODFLOW6 code. I thought I had brew installed, but my computer can't seem to find it. Any help getting MODFLOW6 compiled would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to https://brew.sh/ and get the homebrew install command from there:

From the command-line run:

```sh
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Add it to the path with:

```sh
sudo echo "export PATH=\"/opt/homebrew/bin/:$PATH\"" >> ~/.zshrc
```

Load the homebrew path into your activate terminal

```sh
source ~/.zshrc
```

Install the meson build system and gfortran

```sh
brew install meson
brew install gfortran
brew install git
```

Acquire the code:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/MODFLOW-USGS/modflow6.git
```

Enter the directory:

```sh
cd modflow6
```

Make a build directory:

```sh
mkdir build
cd build
```

Build the makefiles:

```sh
meson ..
```

Compile the code:

```sh
ninja
```

The compiled code is now at:

```
modflow6/build/utils/mf5to6
```

You can even add this to your path with:

```sh
sudo echo 'export PATH="$HOME/modflow6/build/utils/mf5to6:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
```

if you want to be able to run `mf5to6` from anywhere.

Alternatively, you can run it from its location using:

```sh
./modflow6/build/utils/mf5to6
```